I need to calculate the time difference in powerBi
I have



Start Time
Completed Time
Target Time




10:30:00
11:45:00
12:00:00


11:00:00
13:00:00
13:00:00


10:00:00
13:45:00
13:00:00



like this i need to calculate the workdone and show the result as positive for the task done before target time and negitive for after target time
this is for the employee work calculation i need to do analysis on this for each person and calculate the total workdone
i have so many employees and there are multiple repitions of the employees like a single employee would have completed before the target time for day one and the next day he exceeded then time like this i need to calculate the entire data and print the total working hours
this is for the employee work calculation i need to do analysis on this for each person and calculate the total workdone
i have so many employees and there are multiple repitions of the employees like a single employee would have completed before the target time for day one and the next day he exceeded then time like this i need to calculate the entire data and print the total working hours

Sample data is great, but a [mcve] is also supposed to specify the expected result.

Create a calculated column on your table:
Duration (hrs) = 

VAR durationVal = 'Table'[Completed Time] - 'Table'[Start Time]
VAR overtime = IF('Table'[Completed Time] > 'Table'[Target Time], -1, 1)

RETURN  durationVal * overtime * 24

Create a measure and add it to a table with the Employee column:
TotalTime = 

VAR thisEmp = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Employee])
RETURN CALCULATE(
                SUMX('Table', [Duration (hrs)])
                , FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Employee] = thisEmp)
            )

Example output:

